A 'symbol not found' error occurs when testing using MockMvc in JUnit 5
An error occurs in the status() function in the test source code below. It would be natural for an error to occur because there is no status() function in the source code. However, I don't see a separate function being created in the source code in books or on the Internet. What is needed to call the status() function?
package kr.jhansol.blog.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import kr.jhansol.blog.dto.AddArticleRequest;
import kr.jhansol.blog.repository.BlogRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class BlogApiControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    BlogRepository blogRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void mockMvcSetUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
        blogRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @DisplayName("Blog write test")
    @Test
    public void addArticle() throws Exception {
        final String url = "/api/articles";
        final String title = "test";
        final String content = "This is test.";
        final AddArticleRequest request = new AddArticleRequest(title, content);
        final String requestBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);

        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(post(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .content(requestBody));

        result.andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
}

When executing the above code, the following error is output.
D:\spring_projects\blog\src\test\java\kr\jhansol\blog\controller\BlogApiControllerTest.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        result.andExpect(status().isCreated());
                         ^
  symbol:   method status()
  location: class BlogApiControllerTest


Solved.
I added the code below to the top of the source code above:
import static

org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

